# Regular Expression - Replace Uppercase with Lowercase and some specifics

Tags: php, regex, replace, notepad++

I would ask if somebody can tell me how to Find and Replace all UPPERCASE letters (*note: non-first letter in the word) and replace them with lowercase and also between span tags. I'm giving an example what result should be

```
StreEt-> Stre<span>e</span>t

TeAcher -> Te<span>a</span>cher

DOg -> D<span>o</span>g

SchoOl -> Scho<span>o</span>l
```

I would prefer to make it directly in Notepad++.

But if is not possible only with regular expression, some advices how to make it in php loop or javascript would be great.

Thank you in advance!

- *I know that posting of topic without any attempts are not tolerated, so excuse me, but have no idea how this could happen.*

Comment: You can do this in CSS without using PHP https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Comment: Will all the inputs you get always have an uppercase first letter ?

Answer (score 2):

With Notepad++, you can do:

Find what: `\B([A-Z]+)\B`
Replace with: `<span>\L$1</span>`

Make sure that `Case sensitive` is checked.

But it doesn't work with cyrillic letter.

Here is a way to do the job with php:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("/\B(\p{Lu}+)\B/u", 
       function ($m) {
         return "<span>".mb_strtolower($m[1], 'UTF-8')."</span>";
       }, 
       "SchoOl чУствую");
echo $str,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Scho<span>o</span>l ч<span>у</span>ствую
```

Comment: Ok this is working perfectly, but now I found an additional problem in my case. I gave you an example with english words, but actually I need to do for Cyrillic letters and this is not fit in [A-Z] :(


Example: чУствую - ч<span>у</span>ствую

Comment: @АнжелМиленов: Try to add Cyrillic letters in the character class.

Comment: @АнжелМиленов: I think it is not possible to do in Npp. See my edit, I've given php script that does the job.

Comment: OK, but I want to make massive replace of more than 1 000 words that can't put them in array, if i take time to grab them one by one I would change the letters manually.
So That's why I need to make the function to find all the Cyrillic words that have UPPERCASE letter  in the middle of the word and swap it with <span>same lowercase  letter</span> and replace them all at once (loop or soomething).

Imagine Text with 100 000 words and find only the words with UPPERCASE letter in it (not first letter) and replace them.

Comment: @АнжелМиленов: Just read the file in a string and apply the preg_replace.

Comment: I stil didn't try your PHP suggest, but I found that in N++ I can search Cyrillic if I change A-Z to А-Я ----  \B([А-Я]+)\B

@Toto: But I can only use for Find function, it is marking correctly the letter, but can't replace it with whatever.. even with normal letter.
Actually the replace didn't work nor with A-Z find, do you think that can be from the version, is it working to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78110/discussion-between---and-toto).